# apt-get resolving hosts error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

My every apt-get command ends with someting like this:

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'rs.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'rs.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'rs.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg      Temporary failure resolving 'rs.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'rs.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'rs.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried --fix-missing, update, autoremove... but problem stays

Comment: Is your DNS configuration functional? Can you resolve the hostnames (like `security.ubuntu.com`) with `dig`?

Comment: can you give us ifconfig screenshot?

Comment: Can you resolve the address http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com via nslookup?